# Finding Reasonable Global Unemployment and Literacy Data

Tags: data-request

Does anyone know of great datasources that catalog unemployment and literacy rates across the world?

Ideally, I'd like to have statistics as granular as possible (country level, city level, regional level), but I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 2):

I work at Quandl and we have a lot of free, open data on the literacy and unemployment rates in many countries. I don't think the data gets as granular as, say, the city level, but I think the data is usually categorized in some other way eg. literacy rates by age group or sex. You can go to [www.quandl.com](http://www.quandl.com) and search for "literacy" and "unemployment" separately. All the related databases will show up. A lot of the data will come from the World Bank. You can also check out the data by country by going to [www.quandl.com/collections](http://www.quandl.com/collections) then you click on "Countries" to the left, then click on the continent and then the country you want to explore. Literacy statistics will usually be found under "Demography" or "Education" and "Unemployment" is listed as a category on its own. Hope this helps!